# hex string from list of integers in swi-prolog

Tags: prolog, hex, swi-prolog, sha

wondering if there's a library call somewhere to convert the crypto libs 
sha1  return format

```
15 ?- sha_hash('howdy', X , []), atom_codes(Y, X).
X = [239, 66, 186, 177, 25, 29, 162, 114, 241|...],
Y = 'ïBº±\031\\035\¢rñ95÷\214\@\036\=àÁ\032\û'.
```

want to convert X to format like

"A34F890F16"

Answer (score 2):

```
?- sha_hash('howdy', X , []),
 atom_codes(Y, X),
 maplist(\I^format('~16R',[I]),X).
```

outputs

```
EF42BAB1191DA272F13935F78C401E3DE0C11AFB
X = [239, 66, 186, 177, 25, 29, 162, 114, 241|...],
Y = 'ïBº±\031\\035\¢rñ95÷\214\@\036\=àÁ\032\û'.
```

But of course the top string is ambiguous...

Alternatively, padding 'by hand' can be done this way (just 1 code here)

```
?- phrase(xinteger(3), L, []),
   (L =[A] -> N = [48,A] ; N = L),
   format('~s',[N]).
```

output

```
03
L = [51],
A = 51,
N = [48, 51] .
```

xinteger//1 requires this include `:- [library(http/dcg_basics)].`

**edit**: I found the specification string for padding:

```
?- format('~`0t~16R~2|', [15]).
0F
true.
```

then the original example now can be written

```
?- sha_hash('howdy', X , []),
     atom_codes(Y, X),
     maplist(\I^format('~`0t~16R~2|',[I]),X).
```

and this outputs

```
EF42BAB1191DA272F13935F78C401E3DE0C11AFB
X = [239, 66, 186, 177, 25, 29, 162, 114, 241|...],
Y = 'ïBº±\031\\035\¢rñ95÷\214\@\036\=àÁ\032\û'.
```

the output can easily be captured by with_output_to

```
atom_to_hex(Atom, Hex) :-
    atom_codes(Atom, Codes),
    with_output_to(Hex, maplist(\I^format('~`0t~16R~2|',[I]), Codes)).
```

All these examples use *library(lambda)*.

Comment: Thanks - your first version's not working, but did put me on the ribght track. For those reading this question, here's my versionasHexByte(X) :-
 X >= 16,
 format('~R', [X]).

asHexByte(X) :-
 X < 16,
 format('0~R', [X]).

% compute a sha1 in the same style as llSHA1String
%
sha1string(Atom, SHAString) :-
 sha_hash(Atom, SHAList, []),
 with_output_to(codes(SHAString) , maplist(asHexByte , SHAList)).

Comment: here's the link to chac's library   http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord

Answer (score 0):

Chac, thanks, your first version put me on right track, but isn't working. For those reading the question, here's my final version

asHexByte(X) :-
    X >= 16,
    format('~R', [X]).

asHexByte(X) :-
    X < 16,
    format('0~R', [X]).

% compute a sha1 in the same style as llSHA1String
%
sha1string(Atom, SHAString) :-
    sha_hash(Atom, SHAList, []),
    with_output_to(codes(SHAString) , maplist(asHexByte , SHAList)).